# Vb.net Mobile Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been assigned a school project in which we're asked to develop a survey app for device/mobile use using VB.net.
I've started learning some Visual Basic, yet I'm failing to understand the following. I've downloaded Visual Studio 2017, do I need to download something extra so that I'm able to program for a mobile device? Or what is it that I need to do? I'm quite confused, I'd really appreciate some sort of help with understanding what's going on.

I've been searching on the Internet quite some time now, and all I've found is "Visual Basic for Windows Phone Developer Tools - RTW", which is a version for 2010 and I'm not quite sure if it's what I need anyway. Another thing I've found is Xamarin.

Any help will be highly appreciated and excuse me for such a dumb question.

Comment: The search phrase you're looking for is *cross platform develop visual studio*.

Comment: I've already downloaded the Visual Studio 2017(community). Is there something else to download and work on? Or when I create a New project and go to Visual Basic, what do I select?

Comment: Yes. I've provided you with the search phrase that will answer your questions. There is more to download, and the results of that search will tell you what you need. This isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: "I've been assigned a school project ... Or what is it that I need to do?"  I'd start by attending class, and paying attention.  Then raising my hand and asking questions of the professor/teacher.

Comment: [xamarin](https://www.visualstudio.com/xamarin/)

Comment: Run the Visual Studio installer and actually look at what workloads and components are available. The installer tells you what each one is for so install the ones you need.

Comment: Err can you actually develop a mobile app with vb.net these days? I always thought you could only do it with c#

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for Xamarin. It lets you use C#, F# and VB.NET code to develop cross-platform apps including native apps for iOS and Android.

Note that Xamarin doesn't completely or directly support VB.NET. You'll have to do the following steps to get started:

1. Create a new C# solution of the type Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms). You need to have the Mobile Development with .NET workload installed for this.
2. In said solution, add a Visual Basic .NET Class Library (.NET Standard). After creating the project, right-click it, click Properties, and change the Default Namespace to match the existing C# project(s).
3. Right-click the VB.NET project again, click "Manage NuGet Packages", then install Xamarin.Forms.
4. After this, you will want to rename Class1.vb to App.vb. Paste the following starter / example code there:

```vbnet
Imports Xamarin.Forms

Public Class App
    Inherits Application

    Public Sub New()

        Dim label = New Label With {
            .HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            .FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, GetType(Label)),
            .Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms with Visual Basic.NET"
        }

        Dim stack = New StackLayout With {
            .VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }

        stack.Children.Add(label)

        Dim page = New ContentPage
        page.Content = stack
        MainPage = page

    End Sub

End Class
```

5. Update the Android and iOS projects so that they reference the Visual Basic .NET project(s), rather than the C# project created by the template. Right-click on the References node in the Android and iOS projects to open the Reference Manager. Untick the C# library and tick the Visual Basic .NET library instead. Do this for both iOS and Android. Finally, delete the C# project. You can now develop your Xamarin project in VB.NET by adding more .vb files as necessary.

Unfortunately, VB.NET has a few limitations in regards to Xamarin:

- You can't write custom renderers or dependency service implementations in VB.NET. These must be written in C# or F#.
- You can't include XAML pages in VB.NET projects. You'll have to use a workaround that involves including XAML pages in a seperate, C#-based, portable class library, referencing it, and populating the XAML models with VB.NET through databinding. Alternatively, [this](https://github.com/Nukepayload2/XamarinFormsXamlVB) may be of help for using XAML with VB.NET.

More info can be found at [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/platform/visual-basic/xamarin-forms).

I know this question is three years old, and that lots of time has passed since that school project, but I hope this answer was helpful to you regardless, and / or that it will be helpful to others who have the same or a similar question. To anyone about to write Xamarin apps in VB.NET or who is currently doing so, I wish you the best of luck!